# Photoshop crashes when creating a new file

Tags: crash, adobe-photoshop

I have one of the latest version of Photoshop cc. Whenever I create a new file, Photoshop crashes. It doesn't give me an  error message, so I went to windows action center, and saw the unreported problems. Here is the error it gives:

```
Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014\Photoshop.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   Photoshop.exe
Application Version:    15.2.0.236
Application Timestamp:  542531ba
Fault Module Name:  PlugPlugOwl.dll
Fault Module Version:   5.2.0.46
Fault Module Timestamp: 5418cc00
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   000000000006d8af
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   a528
Additional Information 2:   a528cadd7f6cfe125ea7a1feeddc7859
Additional Information 3:   dda9
Additional Information 4:   dda9ef64e8a7401c7fc34145247bbb84
```

This only happens when I create new files, but I can open existing files.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Photoshop?

Comment: No. Is there anything else I can do to fix it?

Comment: I have seen this kind of problem with older versions i.e. CS6. You should consider updating your video/graphics card driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the latest update of CC?

This is the version I have installed 
Adobe Photoshop Version: 2015.0.0 20150529
Operating System: Mac OS 10.10.4

You can easily reinstall the program through Creative Cloud. If the program keeps crashing after a reinstall I'd monitor the usage of memory and CPU while trying to create a new file. This is what I let my photoshop use

Memory available to Photoshop: 14853 MB

Memory used by Photoshop: 70 %

You can find your own info in the top menu help/system info

Answer (score 0):

In my case Photoshop crashes if the clipboard isn't empty and I'm trying to make a new file.

You can clear the clipboard by typing the following command to Terminal:
pbcopy < /dev/null

I hope this helps you..